# iTextSharp doesn't show all columns

Tags: c#, itext

I recently started using `itextsharp` and have been using it to create a PDF report using web service in asp.net. My code in the web service is shown below. My problem is, it does not show the first 3 columns data.

I think  the problem is in the `dt.Rows`.

```
        string[] strFile = Directory.GetFiles(strUploadPath);

        Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(strUploadPath), File.Delete);

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strUploadPath + "/" + strFilename, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        Font font5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
        float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };
        table.SetWidths(widths);
        table.WidthPercentage = 200;
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase());
        int j = 1;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (j <= (dt.Columns.Count))
            {

                //table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ToString(),font5));
                //table.AddCell(new Phrase(j.ToString(),font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
            }
            j++;
        }

        int k = 1;
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(k.ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[5].ToString(), font5));
               // table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[6].ToString(), font5));
                //                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[7].ToString(), font5));

            }
            k++;
        }
        document.Add(table);
        document.CloseDocument();
        document.Close();
        return strFilename;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `table.WidthPercentage = 200` is a good idea? This after all means that the table shall be twice as wide as the page minus margins...

Comment: Thanks for your information its working

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an answer.

Comment: @NiroseBasnyat Please accept mkl's answer (checkmark near the score below), as it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code of the OP contains this line:

```
table.WidthPercentage = 200;
```

This causes the table to be twice (200%) as wide as the page minus margins. Thus, it is partially hidden.

When setting the table width using the `WidthPercentage` property, one usually shouldn't set it above 100.

As the OP meanwhile confirmed, the appropriate change causes the code to work properly.